# Error message in Words With Friends is preventing download? - "You already own this item."

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I am trying to setup my replaced phone back up for Words With Friends as it was before, but
I am getting this error:

> "You already own this item."

when trying to re-purchase the Ultimate Play Pack.

It may be related to the fact that Words With Friends was moved to my data originally. How do I get past this and/or re-purchase ultimate pack and other items?

I have a few apps that I want back on my phone. Will I have to re-purchase them or is there a way get re-installed with or without repurchasing?

Comment: Some apps have a restore purchases button, usually located in the settings. Have you tried looking at that?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to contact the Words With Friends developers and request that they restore your purchases. They should restore automatically if you're logging into app with the same credentials however, some developers tend not to use this method so you have to buy the packs again. It's an easy way to make a few extra dollars.

The fact you're getting the message that you've already purchased the pack is a good sign. Get a hold of the developers and see if there is anything they can do.